# Dictionary inside a list in python

Tags: python

This is what I have

```
d= [{'abc':1,'cde':2},
    {'abc':3,'cde':4},
    {'abc':5,'cde':6},
    {'abc':7,'cde':8}]
```

This is what I want:

```
abc = [1,3,5,7]
cde = [2,4,6,8]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
abc, cde = [x['abc'] for x in d], [x['cde'] for x in d]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
abc = [item['abc'] for item in d]
cde = [item['cde'] for item in d]
```